# python aiomysql quering time increasing with number of parallel tasks

Tags: python, asynchronous, aio-mysql, anyio

I'm using python's aiomysql to query MySQL database in async apps. Also I use anyio to run parallel tasks with create_task_group. Sometimes I need to obtain data by chunks from mysql db and due to speed up quering I create tasks group and run queries in parallel, but  I faced the problem that single query time increasing with number of tasks. There is a snippet to provide an example:

```py
import os
import aiomysql
from time import time
from anyio import run, create_task_group
from dotenv import load_dotenv

diffs = []  # contains each single query time
tot_reqs = 0  # count number of total requests


async def measure(pool):
    global diffs
    global tot_reqs

    async with pool.acquire() as conn:
        start_time = time()
        while True:
            t1 = time()
            cur = await conn.cursor()
            sql = "select * from ttable limit 10000"
            await cur.execute(query=sql)
            await cur.close()

            diffs.append(time() - t1)
            tot_reqs += 1
            if len(diffs) > 9:  # print mean time of every 10 queries
                print(
                    f"[{time()-start_time:.2f}s since started] Mean query time: {sum(diffs)/len(diffs)} (total requests performed: {tot_reqs})"
                )
                diffs = []


async def case():
    db_env_prefix = "SOME_MYSQL"
    pool = await aiomysql.create_pool(
        host=os.getenv(db_env_prefix + "_HOST"),
        port=int(os.getenv(db_env_prefix + "_PORT") or 3306),
        user=os.getenv(db_env_prefix + "_USERNAME"),
        password=os.getenv(db_env_prefix + "_PASSWORD"),
        db=os.getenv(db_env_prefix + "_DB"),
        maxsize=10,
        autocommit=True,
        pool_recycle=600,
    )
    async with create_task_group() as tg:
        for _ in range(10):
            tg.start_soon(measure, pool)
    pool.close()
    await pool.wait_closed()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    load_dotenv()
    run(case)
```

the printed output is:

```
[0.83s since started] Mean query time: 0.5825932741165161 (total requests performed: 10)
[2.95s since started] Mean query time: 0.989139986038208 (total requests performed: 20)
[4.23s since started] Mean query time: 1.238171124458313 (total requests performed: 30)
[5.53s since started] Mean query time: 1.2967675924301147 (total requests performed: 40)
[6.83s since started] Mean query time: 1.2985524892807008 (total requests performed: 50)
[8.14s since started] Mean query time: 1.3030725479125977 (total requests performed: 60)
[9.44s since started] Mean query time: 1.3051365852355956 (total requests performed: 70)
[10.75s since started] Mean query time: 1.3047129154205321 (total requests performed: 80)
[12.05s since started] Mean query time: 1.3064133167266845 (total requests performed: 90)
[13.36s since started] Mean query time: 1.3030510425567627 (total requests performed: 100)
```

so by running 10 tasks in parallel in ~13 seconds I've got about 100 requests finished with mean time 1.3 secs by query. Then I run only one task by:

```
async with create_task_group() as tg:
        for _ in range(1):
            tg.start_soon(measure, pool)
```

I got

```
[1.24s since started] Mean query time: 0.12407510280609131 (total requests performed: 10)
[2.54s since started] Mean query time: 0.13026781082153321 (total requests performed: 20)
[3.85s since started] Mean query time: 0.13041894435882567 (total requests performed: 30)
[5.16s since started] Mean query time: 0.13082268238067626 (total requests performed: 40)
[6.47s since started] Mean query time: 0.13111093044281005 (total requests performed: 50)
[7.78s since started] Mean query time: 0.13118529319763184 (total requests performed: 60)
[9.09s since started] Mean query time: 0.1312186002731323 (total requests performed: 70)
[10.40s since started] Mean query time: 0.13101680278778077 (total requests performed: 80)
[11.72s since started] Mean query time: 0.13155796527862548 (total requests performed: 90)
[13.03s since started] Mean query time: 0.131210994720459 (total requests performed: 100)
```

the same 100 requests in ~13 secs (single task with ~x10 faster single query, mean query time is 0.13 sec).
There is no any cpu-bounded tasks, only IO requests.

So, by increasing number of tasks there is no actual improvement of quering time: the more tasks the slower single query. I tried to query different tables, change mysql configs like increasing innodb_thread_concurrency, innodb_read_io_threads etc. And actually it doesnt look like problem with table/db configuration since when I run the same code in many terminals at the same time, single query time don't struggle and works as I expected from tg.start_soon approach. Multiprocessing will help but this it's has own disadvantages. And, again, its strange behaviour for IO task, nothing should block async request.

UPD:
As requested in comments:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT 'SLEEPING MDB Ram use', COUNT(*),SUM(time),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command="Sleep";
+----------------------+----------+-----------+------------------+----------------------+
| SLEEPING MDB Ram use | COUNT(*) | SUM(time) | SUM(memory_used) | SUM(max_memory_used) |
+----------------------+----------+-----------+------------------+----------------------+
| SLEEPING MDB Ram use |        1 |       309 |            79632 |               162472 |
+----------------------+----------+-----------+------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: Alex, Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide performance improving suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Sure, https://justpaste.it/8wo9l
But as I said, it works as expected with multiprocessing or then I run script from many terminals. In each separate process time remains in ~0.13 per single query for 5-10 terminals. Queries slowing down only if I spawn many tasks in single process, without any significant CPU or RAM consuption.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Any SSD or NVME used for data storage?  C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; text results needed to complete WORKLOAD analysis, please.  Thanks for data posted.  587 sleeping processes should be of concern - resources are not being released in a timely manner.  CONNECT, PROCESS, CLOSE is likely missing the CLOSE at times.

Comment: @WilsonHauck there are [global variables](https://justpaste.it/fnsza)
For storage used internal mac's storage APPLE SSD AP0256Z (which seems to be NVMe). I've got almost the same amount of sleeping process just after reload of laptop and after mysql.server stop command

Comment: @.Alex-Monik The SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;stopped at slave_compressed_protocol,OFF The are more critical lines that I need to complete your analysis. Please replace with a complete TEXT result of SVGV in a new link for us. Also please post TEXT results in your Question the results of this query. SELECT 'SLEEPING MDB Ram use', COUNT(*),SUM(time),SUM(memory_used),SUM(max_memory_used) FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE command="Sleep"; –

Comment: Alex, Can you login as ROOT and get a SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; and post it?

Comment: @WilsonHauck sorry, there is the rest of svgv https://justpaste.it/e3jx2 and I also added there SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
thread_pool_size=6  # from 8 - suggestion in doc is 80% of your 8 cores max
table_open_cache_instances=1  # from 8 until you have more than 1,000 tables
net_buffer_length=98304  # from 16384 to reduce packet in/out count
innodb_io_capacity=900  # from 200 to user move of your NVME IOPS
tmp_table_size=33554532  # from 16M to expand capacity
max_heap_table_size=33554532  # from 16M to reduce created_tmp_disk_tables
```

There are more opportunities to improve performance.  Please view my profile.

Expecting your queries to complete quicker.  When streaming a single set of queries through one connection you may not achieve as much parallel processing as you hoped for.  Please post new times to complete after implementation, if time permits.

Comment: unfortunately doesnt help.
single tasks time:
...
[12.08s since started] Mean query time: 0.1350322961807251 (total requests performed: 90)

vs 10 tasks
[10.71s since started] Mean query time: 1.312420916557312 (total requests performed: 80)

Comment: .Alex, Could you add your processid to the output and print on count of >99 rather than 9 and run with multiple logons as if running for 10 different people to see degradation when you have 10 connections banging on the server?

Comment: I didn't notice difference if use different users https://justpaste.it/dvml0
If run in parallel in different processes then it works as expected event with high cpu load (fans were really noisy)

Comment: I am pleasantly surprised fall off was no more significant when truly parallel processing multiple log on's, but then this is not a real production workload with queries gathering data from everywhere, not just one table involved dynamically.

Comment: Please view my profile and get in touch, there may be things we can help you resolve in production world.

Comment: The number of your sleeping processes should be a concern.  Something is not following the pattern of Connect, Process, Close to release resources.  30 seconds of General Query Log would allow you to confirm.  Every Connect, should be followed by a Quit less than one second after the request is completed and data is delivered to release the resources rather than letting them sleep. You should not depend on WAIT_TIMEOUT to bail you out because most systems have this set to 28800 which is 8 hours later and some part of the resources only get released with Stop/Start of instance.

Comment: Okay, thank you anyway, if find something will let you know